# How to Keep First Row and Second Row of Ms. Word Table in one page in BI Publisher Report?

Tags: ms-word, reporting, peoplesoft, bi-publisher

My institution is using BI Publisher (Ms.Word add on) with Peoplesoft.

Now, I'm doing a report that will print a name and it's description in table format repeatedly. In some cases, the first and second row of the table will be separated in different page. I already tried to check the "Keep Lines Together" and deselect "allow row to break across pages" setting, but only worked with static table, not with table contains BI Publisher fields.

This is the screen shot (look at the red arrow).
[First and second row of table are separated in different page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAThL.png)

Anyone able to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: it was done..just create 1x1 table and set it to not allow break across pages. Then, put the the main table into that 1x1 table. Place the repeating tags outside the 1x1 table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was done..just create 1x1 table and set it to not allow break across pages. Then, put the the main table into that 1x1 table. Place the repeating tags outside the 1x1 table.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by this way.
Insert any filed into the bottom of the table,then change the filed property as

```
<?split-by-page-break:?>
```